# Recibir datos de axios delete en mi API REST hecha con PHP

Tags: php, reactjs, axios, delete

Tengo una pequeña App web realizada con ReactJS ya que estoy aprendiendo sobre dicho framework.
Por ahora sólo es una app donde puedes registrar actividades, visualizarlas, marcarlas como realizadas y borrarlas. El problema está en los último, en borrar.
Mediante peticiones con axios puedo obtener y crear datos nuevos, así como actualizar los mismos (cuando marco una tarea como realizada), pero cuando trato de realizar `axios.delete` no consigo la manera de poder enviar y recibir los datos sin que haya algún problema.
Mi backend está codificado en PHP puro (o sea, no uso Laravel ni ningún otro framework PHP), y cuando pulso el botón en mi frontend para eliminar el dato me da error de CORS aún cuando las cabeceras están descritas en el código PHP que debería recibir la petición delete de axios.
Aquí el código, cualquier duda espero sus comentarios a fin de aclararles mejor el problema y así llegar a una solución ya que esto me está volviendo loco.

```js
deleteTask = async(id) => {

    const tasks = this.state.tasks.filter(task => task.id !== id);
    this.setState({

      tasks: tasks

    })

    await axios.delete(url + `delete/${id}`)
      .then(res => {

        console.log(res.data)

      })
      .catch(error => {

        console.log(error.message)

      })

  }
```

```
<?php 

 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, 
 Access-Control-Request-Method");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE");

 require_once('../modelo/conexion.php');
 require_once('../modelo/consultas.php');

 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://button")); //El id es enviado por un botón puesto en la lista donde se muestran las tarea

 if($data){

   $id = $data -> id;

   $consulta = new Consultas();
   $consulta -> delete($id);

 } else {

   echo json_encode('An error has been ocurred in task delete petition. Please, try again.' . $data -> id);

 }

?>
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Resolví todo (de alguna extraña manera) cambiando el `php//button` por `php//input` y editando la línea del método `axios.delete` a `await axios.delete(url + 'delete/', {data: { id: id }})`.

Comment: No es una forma extraña, porque [`php://input`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input) se refiere a la recepción de datos en una petición y nada tiene que ver con elementos HTML; para este tipo de peticiones, siempre es `input` (entrada, en inglés), no puede ser _button_, _div_ ni nada parecido. Lo segundo tampoco es extraño, porque con la edición ya estás enviando un _JSON_ válido.

Comment: Si elaboras un poco más el texto de la actualización, podrías publicarlo como respuesta, se vale [responder tus propias preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4879/responder-mi-propia-pregunta-cual-es-el-sentido-y-a-d%c3%b3nde-nos-lleva), así ayudas a otros usuarios que tengan problemas similares.